# How to extend cache ttl (time-to-live) in django-redis?

Tags: django, caching, redis, ttl

I'm using django 1.5.4 and django-redis 3.7.1

I'd like to **extend cache's ttl(time-to-live)** when I retrieved it.

Here is sample code

```
from django.core.cache import cache

foo = cache.get("foo)

if not foo:
    cache.set("foo", 1, timeout=100)
else:
    // Extend Cache's Time-To-Live something like it
    cache.ttl("foo") = 200
```

I tried to search this option at [django-redis-docs](http://niwibe.github.io/django-redis/#_why_use_django_redis), but I couldn't find it.

However, I noticed that designate time-to-live value for existing cache is available at redis native command like "`Expire foo 100`"

I know that using `cache.set` once more make same effect, but I'd like to use more simple method with time-to-live attribute.

Comment: If you found the solution, please post it as an answer, instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks for your comment. I've answered by myself.

Comment: Yup! Thanks for entering the answer! And for coming back to want to update with the answer, in the first place!

Answer (score 7):

To extend a ttl(time-to-live) of the django-redis cache record use **expire(key, timeout)**

> Django-Redis: [Expire & Persist](http://jazzband.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_expire_persist)

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set("foo", 1, timeout=100)
cache.ttl("foo")
>>> 100
```

You cannot extend ttl(time-to-live) if the key already expired

```
if cache.ttl("foo") > 0:
    cache.expire("foo", timeout=500)

cache.ttl("foo")
>>> 500
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.

(1) Using '**Raw Client Access**' and (2) Extend TTL value **without overwriting**

Please refer following code.

```
from redis_cache import get_redis_connection

con = get_redis_connection('default')

con.expire(":{DB NUMBER at settings.py}:" + "foo", 100)
```