# Unable to extend cache while working with imagemagick

Tags: r, imagemagick

I am working with imagemagick in R and while using it to convert an image into text, am facing a problem where I get an error which says "Unable to Extend Cache". I have referred to current website and it did give me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463030/how-to-extend-cache-ttl-time-to-live-in-django-redis) result which does not solve my problem. I have also refereed to [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16252) external source, but it does not work as well. My CPU usage seems to be fine.

Below is the code I am trying to run:

```
test3 <- image_read("D:/xyz/Untitled112.jpg") %>%
image_resize("5300") %>%
image_convert(colorspace = 'gray') %>%
image_trim() %>%
image_ocr()
cat(test3)
write.table(test3, "D:/xyz/untitled.txt", sep="\t")
```

If someone could help, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the temporary files from your system and then try again. It would free up some space and should ideally work as per my experience with a similar error.